# Unable to connect to local MySQL DB using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a local database that I can connect to no problem using straight php

[image: Working Example]

However, when I use the same settings in Laravel, I get an access denied error message

[image]

I checked stackoverflow for this type of error and most cases is solved by using `127.0.0.1`. I made sure to try both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` whenever asked for host/server.

Also, I made sure root had sufficient privileges

[image: mysql User Root Privileges]

Here are my configuration settings, I tried to use different accounts, other than root, and also changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost (and the opposite)

database.php file

[image]

.env file

[image]

Hoping to learn this framework, I've heard great things. Appreciate any help

Comment: In the database.php file add your database, username and password instead of forge.

Comment: Does the database `homestead` exist and allow access from localhost? The only difference between native Pdo and laravel is laravel will try to connect a specific database not just the server as your example so likely db related. Also your password is shown in the trace

Comment: @KinshukLahiri it's overridden in the .env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying the connection both with the script and laravel from a different Server like homestead.

Normally there are restrictions that you can't connect from remote (i.e. from a VM like homestead) to a certain server (i.e. localhost) with the root user.

Possible Solutions:
1. Create another user with the relevant permissions on mysql and connect with that one.
2. Look in the web for how to allow remote connections
3. Go the laravel way and use the homestead DB inside of the VM

Comment: that makes sense. New to virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure you typed the password correctly?

Second, are you using the homestead virtual box? If yes, the default user is "homestead" and the pass is "secret" without quotes of course. Try putting that in the .env file

Comment: I was not using homesteads virtual box's mysql. I thought I could connect to my local DB. @hogan explained why that is difficult. Thanks for your help