# laravel 5 - when trying to retrive data from phpmyadmin: SQLSTATE HY000 1698 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: laravel

That's my first post - I hope my problem explanation will be easy to understand. I just started with Laravel5.

I want to retrive data from mysql database that was successfully created using migrations. I'm following laracast series. I created route, controller and view to display the data. Unfortunatelly, when I enter browser to see it, I constantly get this error:

```
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nqK6.png)

My .env and database.php files are configured. Also, I can do migrations with no error (and I see result in phpmyadmin to which I can log in). When I type php artisan tinker, I can do various operations on my databases. The problem arises only when I want to display data in my laravel site.

I did vast research of the problem and tried numerus tips like:

1.change local host to 127.0.0.1

2.change my database login and pass for homeostead, secret

3.I did

```
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY     'Your_Password';`
```

When I type `mysql --user=root -p` I can log in but command `show databases` acts like never ending and shows nothing.

and other ...

Now, I'm at loss for ideas what to do next, please help me. I will appreciate that a lot cos I'm really stucked at this point!

my .env file:

```
`DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=haslo`
```

I use homeostead and Laravel 5 on Windows 7
Server type: MySQL5.7.15
PHP version: 7.1
Apache/2.4.23, PHP/7.1

Comment: Make sure that database 'laravel' exists, create one manually, then check file /config/database.php in your laravel project, set your username and password in section 'Database Connections' and correct database driver.

Comment: Yes it exists (what I mean I created laravel database manually in phpmyadmin and filled it doing migrations). My file /config/database.php has same values as .env and I did choose mysql as default.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my answer at [Unable to connect to local MySQL DB using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680665/unable-to-connect-to-local-mysql-db-using-laravel/39681455#39681455)

That could be the answer for you as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if this (fact that I'm trying to connect from VM to my local phpmyadmin without permission for remote access) solves my problem. I'm still working on configuration so that to enable remote access. But this is great hint - thank you!

Just one more thing. Do I understand it well? In nutshell: I have one local database in phpmyadmin and once I enter it from terminal doing migrations (I enter db locally) but when executing laravel code (then I enter db remotely)?

Comment: Usually its the other way around. You have a VM like homestead which mimics your server. Your DB and Webserver are located there. Your folder is mapped so that nginx (thats the default homestead webserver) So all you do is edit your files one the side that you prefer (where you have sublime text or so installed) and nginx will load the files and connect to the db inside of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you use homestead with vagrant, then laravel will be lunched inside vagrant and 127.0.0.1,3306 will mean the mysql inside vagrant, type vagrant ssh and check for the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
Php artisan config:clear
```